# Pearson Correlation without using zero element in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation, pearson

I have 2 example vector in Matlab :

`A = [5,3,3,0,4,1,5,0,2,5,5,0,5,3,4,0,1,4,4,0,4,2];
  B = [1,0,0,0,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];`

When, I try to calculate pearson correlation with manual method and do it with excel
I have the same result (**0.667**)

1       0,667
0,667   1

But when I tried in MatLab with simple code:

```
pearson = corr(A',B');
```

it return the result with different score (**0,2139**).

1        0,2139
 0,2139   1

Maybe Its happen because the zero score(0) is using to calculate it. In happen because the missing value will be replace by zero(0) in matlab.

In Pearson Correlation that only use co-rated value to calculate it. (see the bold value)

A = [**5**,3,3,0,**4**,1,**5**,0,2,5,5,0,**5**,3,**4**,0,1,4,4,0,4,2];
B = [**1**,0,0,0,**1**,0,**4**,0,0,0,0,4,**4**,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

or it can make simple :

A = [**5**,**4**,**5**,**5**,**4**];
B = [**1**,**1**,**4**,**4**,**1**];

Does anyone know, how to make simple code for this?
I have try it in procedural code :
first, make function corated, average_corated, then at last calculate similarity.
it cost too much time.

Thanks before :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the index for where the good data is located first:

```
goodData = A~=0 & B~=0; %# true wherever there's data for both A and B

pearson = corr(A(goodData),B(goodData));
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot.maybe you forgot to use (') pearson = corr(A(goodData)',B(goodData)'); because corr only used for calculate column size.
thanks a lot again.

Comment: may I ask you 1 question again? when it become 1 matrices (A = [5,3,3,0,4,1,5,0,2,5,5,0,5,3,4,0,1,4,4,0,4,2; 1,0,0,0,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
how to use it?

Comment: @user413262: then, you write: `goodData = any(A,1);pearson=corr(A(1,goodData),A(2,goodData));`

Comment: hmm..maybe i use this : goodData = A(:,1)~=0 & A(:,2)~=0; X=corr(A(goodData,1),A(goodData,2));

Comment: I have a problem again Jonas. Can you help me?
when I used m x n matrices (m,n>3). I cant get right correlation for each column (ex : column 1 and column 2, column 3 and column 4, etc). here is my code :
size_matrix = size(training_matrix);
size_user_matrix = size_matrix(1);A=training_matrix'; for u=1 : size_user_matrix
        for v=1 : size_user_matrix
goodData(u,v) = A(:,u)~=0 & A(:,v)~=0;
      pearson(u,v)=corr(A(goodData,u),A(goodData,v));
            end      
        end

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a one liner: `pearson = corr(A(B ~= 0)', B(B ~= 0)')`

`B ~= 0` creates a binary matrix of size `size(B)` which is `1` if the corresponding entry in `B` is not zero, and `0` otherwise. You can also index into a matrix using binary matrices of the same size, so this should always work if the `size(A) == size(B)`.

Comment: thanks before for answering :)
but when I used it in MatLab it still dont get the answer :
A(B ~= 0)' = have 6 value
B(A ~= 0)' = have 17 value

. its should be both of them have the same value and dont have zero score on them :)

btw, thanks again :)