# Compute Pearson correlation avoiding zero values

Tags: matlab, correlation, pearson

I have a sparse matrix `A(m,n)`, where `n` are the variables and `m` the observations. I want to compute the Pearson correlation among all the n variables.

I have some missing observations, e.g. if `A(2,3)` is not available it means that I don't have such observation, so if, for example, I need to compute the correlation between column 3 and column 4, I must discard row 2, even if `A(2,4)` is available. This is how Pearson correlation is normally computed.

In MATLAB, instead, the function `corrcoef()` consider all the values, including the missing ones (which are considered zeros). Is there a simple way to avoid this? A very similar question is available here [Pearson Correlation without using zero element in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911052/pearson-correlation-without-using-zero-element-in-matlab) but a working solution is provided just for the comparison among two vectors and not for a generic matrix `A(m,n)` where `n > 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jonas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7911251/5211833) on the question you linked works for you as well if you generalise it:

```
Col1 = 2;
Col2 = 3;
A=magic(3); A(1,1)=0;
gooddata = A(:,Col1)~=0 & A(:,Col2)~=0;
pearson = corr(A(gooddata,Col1),A(gooddata,Col2));
```

Thus, looped it would be:

```
for ii = 1:length(A(1,:))
    for jj = ii:length(A(1,:))
       gooddata = A(:,ii)~=0 & A(:,jj)~=0;
       pearson(ii,jj) = corr(A(gooddata,ii),A(gooddata,jj));
    end
end
```

Comment: I am not sure if I got your answer, I don't need that all elements are non zero, I need to keep the rows where both the values, for the two columns I am considering, are not zero.
If I try your code adding just a zero element to a matrix: a=magic(3); a(1,1)=0; then a(~any(a,1)) gives me an empty matrix

Comment: Thanks but It doesn't provide a solution to the problem: in your example when I compute the correlation between col 2 and 3 I need all three rows but the first one has been deleted because of the zero in A(1,1)

Comment: this works for a single correlation computation, I have to compute the correlations for a big matrix having thousands of columns and I am looking for a simple way to do it without loops

Comment: Simple means loops. You can loop over `Col1` and `Col2`. Besides, since the MATLAB engine overhaul loops are not that slow anymore.

Comment: @Eugenio your goals should always be to have functional code first, then figure out where optimize. You can't *a priori* assume that a loop solution is slowest.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- Donald Knuth

Comment: Ok, I accepted the answer because technically is right, but it just adds loops to a previous existing answer, which is something that any matlab user can do.